# Set textbox line appearance to a gradient using Word VBA? (2016)

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

**Context**: I'm setting up a macro to format textboxes *independently of current template or textbox defaults*, in Word 2016. To be clear, **No,** I cannot depend on the "Set Textbox Defaults" option.

The design I have to replicate puts a linear gradient on the outer textbox's border, going from a dark color at the top to white at the bottom. Pretty simple, right? Except I can't figure out how to tell VBA to accomplish this.

Normally I record a macro to see which properties to change, but the Macro recorder isn't saving any edits to the Shape format.

Manually I got as far as outputting the **.Pattern** used on the **textbox.Line** object via Debug.Print: Word returns -2 (msoPatternMixed) which is "Not supported" according to Microsoft's reference docs.

I don't know how to get any further.

Could anyone share some example code that'd let me set the line gradient through VBA?

Or: tell me how to force the Macro Recorder to save the changes I'm making in the **Format Shape** dialog? It's incredibly annoying that it refuses to show me anything.

Thanks!

Comment: The object model doesn't replicate all the functionality of the UI. AFAIK applying a gradient to a text box border is one of the things that is missing. One workaround is to format a text box and save it as a Building Block to the "Text Boxes" gallery. Then it can either be inserted manually or using code.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Do you know if it's possible to save a building block and populate it to another file via VBA? Like I mentioned, I have to make this work across multiple documents and different templates.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. The Building Block can be stored in the same template as the code, if using code is necessary. Or it can be stored in a template located in the Startup folder, in which case it is automatically loaded and made available to all documents either for manual insertion or via VBA.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Thanks, that last suggestion is something I can implement and sounds like it'd solve a couple long workarounds on other projects too. I appreciate your time :)